# Visual Studio Team Services (project) + SASS

Tags: visual-studio, sass

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível "compilar" o SASS em um projeto no Visual Studio 2015 sem ter que instalar nada.

**Motivo**: Estou precisando de algo que eu de um GET no projeto usando o Visual Studio Team Services, rodar ele e funcionar tudo, sem necessitar de nenhum tipo de instalação prévia para rodar.

***(Get projeto -> Rodar -> 100% funcionando com SASS)***

Até agora só encontrei o Koala e pelo prompt instalando o Ruby; o que no meu caso não podem ser usados pois eles são **instaláveis**.

Links ou qualquer coisa que ajude a encontrar uma solução é bem vindo, pois estou a dias procurando uma solução.

Comment: O arquivos SASS precisa ser processado pra virar CSS. Se você não pode instalar nada, não vai conseguir fazer isso.

Comment: Pode usar uma solução pelo terminal ou alguma solução Node.js? Pode usar um bundle dentro do código? Porque no NuGet tem alguns compiladores de SASS/Scss...